# Common factor of a coefficient

Tags: matlab

I am doing a computer engineering project whereby I must extract what I believe to be a common factor from a multiplication and addition operation, which my friend said can be done in MATLAB.

Basically if I have some coefficients x,y, and z, and I want to compute the result of multiplying against a set of numbers which can change and summing the result as such

3x+2y+1z

I would like to get a factor (lets call it "w") from the coefficients so instead of doing 3 multiplies and 3 additions, I can just do 3 additions and one multiply and get the same result as such:

w(1+2+3)

My friend said this can be done in MATLAB to find that "w" but I have been googling "factoring from expression" and different variations of it but to no avail. I would appreciate it if anyone you understands what I am trying to do in MATLAB could point me in the right direction

Thanks.

**EDIT**
x,y,z, and w are numbers, I just put them as variables to illustrate my point

Comment: In your example, what would `w` be?

Comment: If they are numbers, then `factor(3*x+2*y+z)` will give the prime decomposition, I don't think you can get the output as `w*(1+2+3)` though.